# Control for displaying level of cost with currency signs

Tags: sapui5

This might be an opinionated question, but I'd like to ask it because capabilities of UI5 are quite broad. I need to have these elements as

[image]

To which I am planning to introduce a custom font. Do you think it's a good solution or is there any better way to do that with some out of the box solutions?

Comment: I really would not introduce a custom font. Unicode covers currency symbols, and most unicode supporting fonts include them anyway. Applying suitable strength or colours to the real characters is likely to better supported ling term.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts is there any ui5 component that can help to use it in XML view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `sap.m.RatingIndicator`.

```xml
<RatingIndicator
  editable="false"
  maxValue="6"
  value="4"
  iconSelected="imageOrIconURI1"
  iconUnselected="imageOrIconURI2"
/>
```

- [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.RatingIndicator)
- [Samples](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/RatingIndicator.html?sap-ui-theme=sap_fiori_3)

In your case, you'll need two images: one for the cash / currency symbol, and one greyed-out version of it. Both URIs should be assigned to `iconSelected` and `iconUnselected` accordingly.

Here is my attempt:

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Core"
], Core => Core.attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/theming/Parameters",
], async (Fragment, JSONModel, ThemeParameters) => {
  "use strict";

  const control = await Fragment.load({
    definition: `<form:SimpleForm xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns="sap.m">
      <Label text="Cost A" />
      <RatingIndicator
        displayOnly="true"
        editable="false"
        maxValue="6"
        value="4"
        iconSelected="{myCurrency>/filled}"
        iconUnselected="{myCurrency>/unfilled}"
      />
      <Label text="Cost B" />
      <RatingIndicator
        displayOnly="true"
        editable="false"
        maxValue="6"
        value="2"
        iconSelected="{myCurrency>/filled}"
        iconUnselected="{myCurrency>/unfilled}"
      />
    </form:SimpleForm>`,
  });

  //==================================================================
  //============= Sample rating indicator icons ======================

  const currencyCode = "€";
  // determine theme-dependent color values for font colors:
  const colorFilled = ThemeParameters.get("sapUiContentForegroundTextColor").replace("#", "%23");
  const colorUnfilled = ThemeParameters.get("sapUiContentImagePlaceholderBackground").replace("#", "%23");
  const model = new JSONModel({ // assign the icon URIs, e.g. data-URI with SVG content:
    filled: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      viewBox='0 0 14 14'>
      <text x='50%' y='66%'
        fill='${colorFilled}'
        dominant-baseline='middle'
        text-anchor='middle'>
        ${currencyCode}
      </text>
    </svg>`,
    unfilled: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 14 14'>
      <text x='50%' y='66%'
        fill='${colorUnfilled}'
        dominant-baseline='middle'
        text-anchor='middle'>
        ${currencyCode}
      </text>
    </svg>`,
  });
  
  control.setModel(model, "myCurrency").placeAt("content");
})));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[image: ui5 rating indicator with text instead of images] [image: ui5 rating indicator with text instead of images - in dark mode]

Since I put a plain text character to the SVG, the "image" is zoomable without losing quality and the color can be also made theme-dependent as shown above. But of course, you can also just use two raster images instead.

Either way, I believe the `RatingIndicator` is a good candidate which could be used instead of creating and maintaining a custom control or custom font.

Comment: Thanks for the example, that's an interesting solution for this problem! I guess I would still need to have smth like a custom control though, just because I also need the popover effect bound to the ranks. If you are interested it's in my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413287/restrict-addeventdelegate-to-parent-hbox-only question. But for the current problem, I think your solution is exactly what's needed.