# restrict addEventDelegate to parent hbox only

Tags: sapui5

This is a custom control created for my previous question [Custom font for currency signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406782/custom-font-for-currency-signs)

I have two `span` elements coming next to each other. They sit in the `FormattedText`. The `FormattedText` itself sits in the `HBox`. 
I want popover fired when user mouses over/out from the `hbox`. Unfortunately, as I have 2 spans this fires separately when user hovers overs them (thus showing 2 separate popovers, when in fact it should be one). My assumption is that this causes because `onmouseover/out` is attached to both spans under the hood. Can I restrict these events to `hbox` only?

```
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/Control',
  'sap/m/FormattedText',
  'sap/m/HBox',
], function (Control, FormattedText, HBox) {

  return Control.extend('drex.control.TherapyCosts', {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        rank: {
          type: 'int',
          defaultValue: 0
        },
      },
      aggregations: {
        _rankedTherapyCost: {type: 'sap.m.FormattedText', multiple: false, singularName: '_rankedTherapyCost'},
        _popover: {type: 'sap.m.Popover', multiple: false, singularName: '_popover'},
        _hbox: {type: 'sap.m.HBox', multiple: false}
      }
    },

    init: function () {
      Control.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    onBeforeRendering: function () {
      const highlighedCurrency = this.getCurrency().repeat(this.getRank());
      const fadedCurrency = this.getCurrency().repeat(7 - this.getRank());
      const _popover = new sap.m.Popover({
        showHeader: false,
        placement: 'VerticalPreferredBottom',
        content: new sap.m.Text({text: 'test'})
      });
      this.setAggregation('_popover', _popover);
      const _formattedText = new FormattedText({
        htmlText:
          `<span class="currencyHighlighted">${highlighedCurrency}</span>` +
          `<span class="currencyFaded">${fadedCurrency}</span>`
      });
      this.setAggregation('_rankedTherapyCost', _formattedText);
      const _hbox = new HBox(
        { items: [this.getAggregation('_rankedTherapyCost')]})
        .addEventDelegate({
          onmouseover: () => {
            this.getAggregation('_popover').openBy(this);
          },
          onmouseout: () => {
            this.getAggregation('_popover').close()
          }
        });
      this.setAggregation('_hbox', _hbox)
    },

    renderer: function (rm, oControl) {
      const _hbox = oControl.getAggregation('_hbox');
      rm.write('<div');
      rm.writeControlData(oControl);
      rm.write('>');
      rm.renderControl(_hbox);
      rm.write('</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the video of the issue
https://streamable.com/fjw408

Comment: i believe you attached event to the HBox and not to the span. am I right? Can you try attaching event to the FormattedText?

Comment: @D.Seah unfortunately I started from that and it was the same behavior. Initially I didn't want to have any hbox at all, just formatted text.

Comment: I'd suggest to keep it simple by using `tooltip` only instead of trying to achieve the same with a Popover. Or what do you have to display on mouseover exactly? Is the app for desktop users only in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is the mouseout event is triggered when the mouse moves out of any child element of the element that is listening for the event. In this case, for example, moving from the emphasised text to the faded text, you get a mouseout event when moving off the emphasised text, which closes the popup, then a mouseover event on the faded text which opens it again.

Since you opening an already open popup doesn't do anything, you only need add a line on mouseout to inspect the element that you've gone to. If it is not a child of the current element, only then close the popover.

```js
if (!this.getDomRef().contains(e.toElement)) {
  popOver.close()
}
```

Building on D.Seah's answer, I've added this to the JSBin. I personally don't like using `onBeforeRendering` and `onAfterRendering` like this, so I've refactored a little to construct everything on init and simply change the controls on property change. This way, you're doing less on rendering for performance reasons.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/Control',
  'sap/m/FormattedText',
], function (Control, FormattedText) {

  Control.extend('TherapyCosts', {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        rank: {
          type: 'int',
          defaultValue: 0
        },
        currency: {
          type: "string",
          defaultValue: "$"
        }
      },
      aggregations: {
        _highlighted: {type: 'sap.m.FormattedText', multiple: false},
        _faded: {type: 'sap.m.FormattedText', multiple: false},
        _popover: {type: 'sap.m.Popover', multiple: false, singularName: '_popover'}
      }
    },

    init: function () {
      Control.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.addStyleClass('therapy-cost');
      
      const highlight = new FormattedText();
      highlight.addStyleClass("currency-highlight");
      this.setAggregation('_highlighted', highlight);

      const faded = new FormattedText();
      faded.addStyleClass("currency-faded");
      this.setAggregation('_faded', faded);
      
      const _popover = new sap.m.Popover({
        showHeader: false,
        placement: 'VerticalPreferredBottom',
        content: new sap.m.Text({text: 'test'})
      });
      this.setAggregation('_popover', _popover);
    },
    
    _changeAggr: function () {
      const highlighedCurrency = this.getCurrency().repeat(this.getRank());
      const highlight = this.getAggregation("_highlighted");
      highlight.setHtmlText(highlighedCurrency);
      
      const fadedCurrency = this.getCurrency().repeat(7 - this.getRank());
      const faded = this.getAggregation("_faded");
      faded.setHtmlText(fadedCurrency);
    },
    
    setRank: function(rank) {
       if (this.getProperty("rank") !== rank) {
         this.setProperty("rank", rank);
         this._changeAggr();
       }
    },

    setCurrency: function(curr) {
       if (this.getProperty("currency") !== curr) {
         this.setProperty("currency", curr);
         this._changeAggr();
       }
    },
    
    renderer: function (rm, oControl) {
      rm.write('<div');
      rm.writeControlData(oControl);
      rm.writeClasses(oControl);
      rm.writeStyles(oControl);
      rm.write('>');
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_highlighted'));
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_faded'));
      rm.write('</div>');
    },
    
    onmouseover: function (e) {
      const popOver = this.getAggregation('_popover');
      popOver.openBy(this);
    },
    
    onmouseout: function (e) {
      if (!this.getDomRef().contains(e.toElement)) {
        const popOver = this.getAggregation('_popover');
        popOver.close();
      }
    }
  });
  (new TherapyCosts({
    rank: 5,
    currency: "£"
  })).placeAt('content')
});
```

```css
.therapy-cost {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.therapy-cost .currency-highlighted {
  color: black;
}

.therapy-cost .currency-faded {
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script 
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact">
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/gukedamemu/3/edit?css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do without the hbox; by just having two formatted text or any sapui5 controls will be ok too.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/Control',
  'sap/m/FormattedText',
], function (Control, FormattedText) {

  Control.extend('TherapyCosts', {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        rank: {
          type: 'int',
          defaultValue: 0
        },
        currency: {
          type: "string",
          defaultValue: "$"
        }
      },
      aggregations: {
        _highlighted: {type: 'sap.m.FormattedText', multiple: false},
        _faded: {type: 'sap.m.FormattedText', multiple: false},
        _popover: {type: 'sap.m.Popover', multiple: false, singularName: '_popover'}
      }
    },

    init: function () {
      Control.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.addStyleClass('therapy-cost')
    },

    onBeforeRendering: function () {
      const highlighedCurrency = this.getCurrency().repeat(this.getRank());
      const highlight = new FormattedText({
        htmlText: highlighedCurrency
      });
      this.setAggregation('_highlighted', highlight);

      const fadedCurrency = this.getCurrency().repeat(7 - this.getRank());
      const faded = new FormattedText({
        htmlText: fadedCurrency
      });
      this.setAggregation('_faded', faded);

      const _popover = new sap.m.Popover({
        showHeader: false,
        placement: 'VerticalPreferredBottom',
        content: new sap.m.Text({text: 'test'})
      });
      this.setAggregation('_popover', _popover);
    },

    renderer: function (rm, oControl) {
      rm.write('<div');
      rm.writeControlData(oControl);
      rm.writeClasses(oControl);
      rm.writeStyles(oControl);
      rm.write('>');
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_highlighted'));
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_faded'));
      rm.write('</div>');
    },
    onAfterRendering: function () {
      const popOver = this.getAggregation('_popover');
      const highlighted = this.getAggregation("_highlighted");
      highlighted.$().addClass("currency-highlighted");
      highlighted.$().hover(function() {
        popOver.openBy(highlighted);
      }, function() {
        popOver.close();
      });
      const faded = this.getAggregation("_faded");
      faded.$().addClass("currency-faded");
    },
  });
  (new TherapyCosts({
    rank: 5
  })).placeAt('content')
});
```

https://jsbin.com/razebuq/edit?css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the example! Looks almost as I wanted, but the faded part should also get a similar popover. Is that possible? @D. Seah

Comment: the same popover or a different popover?

Comment: should be exactly the same one

Comment: https://jsbin.com/razebuq/edit?css,js,output - a tiny change

Comment: you are repeating exactly the issue I have shown in my video :) https://streamable.com/fjw408how how to show it actually as one popover instead of 2 separate ones when hovering over different parts of text?

Comment: can you try again?